# Cropping Square Video using FFmpeg

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg

## Updated

So I am trying to decode a mp4 file, crop the video into a square, and then re encode it back out to another mp4 file.  This is my current code but there are a few issues with it.

One is that the video doesn't keep its rotation after the video has been re encoded

Second is that the frames get outputted in a very fast video file that is not the same length as the original

Third is that there is no sound

Lastly and most importantly is do I need AVFilter to do the frame cropping or can it just be done per frame as a resize of the frame and then encoded back out.

```
const char *inputPath = "test.mp4";
const char *outPath = "cropped.mp4";
const char *outFileType = "mp4";

static AVFrame *oframe = NULL; 
static AVFilterGraph *filterGraph = NULL;  
static AVFilterContext *crop_ctx = NULL;
static AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx = NULL;
static AVFilterContext *buffer_ctx = NULL;

int err;

int crop_video(int width, int height) {

av_register_all();
avcodec_register_all();
avfilter_register_all();

AVFormatContext *inCtx = NULL;

// open input file
err = avformat_open_input(&inCtx, inputPath, NULL, NULL);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("error at open input in\n");
    return err;
}

// get input file stream info
err = avformat_find_stream_info(inCtx, NULL);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("error at find stream info\n");
    return err;
}

// get info about video
av_dump_format(inCtx, 0, inputPath, 0);

// find video input stream
int vs = -1;
int s;
for (s = 0; s < inCtx->nb_streams; ++s) {
    if (inCtx->streams[s] && inCtx->streams[s]->codec && inCtx->streams[s]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        vs = s;
        break;
    }
}

// check if video stream is valid
if (vs == -1) {
    printf("error at open video stream\n");
    return -1;
}

// set output format
AVOutputFormat * outFmt = av_guess_format(outFileType, NULL, NULL);
if (!outFmt) {
    printf("error at output format\n");
    return -1;
}

// get an output context to write to
AVFormatContext *outCtx = NULL;
err = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outCtx, outFmt, NULL, NULL);
if (err < 0 || !outCtx) {
    printf("error at output context\n");
    return err;
}

// input and output stream
AVStream *outStrm = avformat_new_stream(outCtx, NULL);
AVStream *inStrm = inCtx->streams[vs];

// add a new codec for the output stream
AVCodec *codec = NULL;
avcodec_get_context_defaults3(outStrm->codec, codec);

outStrm->codec->thread_count = 1;

outStrm->codec->coder_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

if(outCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
    outStrm->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}

outStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio = outStrm->sample_aspect_ratio = inStrm->sample_aspect_ratio;

err = avio_open(&outCtx->pb, outPath, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("error at opening outpath\n");
    return err;
}

outStrm->disposition = inStrm->disposition;
outStrm->codec->bits_per_raw_sample = inStrm->codec->bits_per_raw_sample;
outStrm->codec->chroma_sample_location = inStrm->codec->chroma_sample_location;
outStrm->codec->codec_id = inStrm->codec->codec_id;
outStrm->codec->codec_type = inStrm->codec->codec_type;

if (!outStrm->codec->codec_tag) {
    if (! outCtx->oformat->codec_tag
        || av_codec_get_id (outCtx->oformat->codec_tag, inStrm->codec->codec_tag) == outStrm->codec->codec_id
        || av_codec_get_tag(outCtx->oformat->codec_tag, inStrm->codec->codec_id) <= 0) {
        outStrm->codec->codec_tag = inStrm->codec->codec_tag;
    }
}

outStrm->codec->bit_rate = inStrm->codec->bit_rate;
outStrm->codec->rc_max_rate = inStrm->codec->rc_max_rate;
outStrm->codec->rc_buffer_size = inStrm->codec->rc_buffer_size;

const size_t extra_size_alloc = (inStrm->codec->extradata_size > 0) ?
(inStrm->codec->extradata_size + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE) :
0;

if (extra_size_alloc) {
    outStrm->codec->extradata = (uint8_t*)av_mallocz(extra_size_alloc);
    memcpy( outStrm->codec->extradata, inStrm->codec->extradata, inStrm->codec->extradata_size);
}

outStrm->codec->extradata_size = inStrm->codec->extradata_size;

AVRational input_time_base = inStrm->time_base;
AVRational frameRate = {25, 1};
if (inStrm->r_frame_rate.num && inStrm->r_frame_rate.den
    && (1.0 * inStrm->r_frame_rate.num / inStrm->r_frame_rate.den < 1000.0)) {
    frameRate.num = inStrm->r_frame_rate.num;
    frameRate.den = inStrm->r_frame_rate.den;
}

outStrm->r_frame_rate = frameRate;
outStrm->codec->time_base = inStrm->codec->time_base;

outStrm->codec->pix_fmt = inStrm->codec->pix_fmt;
outStrm->codec->width = width;
outStrm->codec->height =  height;
outStrm->codec->has_b_frames =  inStrm->codec->has_b_frames;

if (!outStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio.num) {
    AVRational r0 = {0, 1};
    outStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio =
    outStrm->sample_aspect_ratio =
    inStrm->sample_aspect_ratio.num ? inStrm->sample_aspect_ratio :
    inStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio.num ?
    inStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio : r0;
}

avformat_write_header(outCtx, NULL);

filterGraph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
if (!filterGraph) {
    printf("could not open filter graph");
    return -1;
}

AVFilter *crop = avfilter_get_by_name("crop");
AVFilter *buffer = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
AVFilter *buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");

char args[512];

snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
         width, height, inStrm->codec->pix_fmt,
         inStrm->codec->time_base.num, inStrm->codec->time_base.den,
         inStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio.num, inStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

err = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffer_ctx, buffer, NULL, args, NULL, filterGraph);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("error initializing buffer filter\n");
    return err;
}

err = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, NULL, NULL, NULL, filterGraph);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("unable to create buffersink filter\n");
    return err;
}
snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "%d:%d", width, height);
err = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&crop_ctx, crop, NULL, args, NULL, filterGraph);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("error initializing crop filter\n");
    return err;
}

err = avfilter_link(buffer_ctx, 0, crop_ctx, 0);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("error linking filters\n");
    return err;
}

err = avfilter_link(crop_ctx, 0, buffersink_ctx, 0);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("error linking filters\n");
    return err;
}

err = avfilter_graph_config(filterGraph, NULL);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("error configuring the filter graph\n");
    return err;
}

printf("filtergraph configured\n");

for (;;) {

    AVPacket packet = {0};
    av_init_packet(&packet);

    err = AVERROR(EAGAIN);
    while (AVERROR(EAGAIN) == err)
        err = av_read_frame(inCtx, &packet);

    if (err < 0) {
        if (AVERROR_EOF != err && AVERROR(EIO) != err) {
            printf("eof error\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (packet.stream_index == vs) {

        //
        //            AVPacket pkt_temp_;
        //            memset(&pkt_temp_, 0, sizeof(pkt_temp_));
        //            AVPacket *pkt_temp = &pkt_temp_;
        //
        //            *pkt_temp = packet;
        //
        //            int error, got_frame;
        //            int new_packet = 1;
        //
        //            error = avcodec_decode_video2(inStrm->codec, frame, &got_frame, pkt_temp);
        //            if(error < 0) {
        //                LOGE("error %d", error);
        //            }
        //
        //            // if (error >= 0) {
        //
        //            // push the video data from decoded frame into the filtergraph
        //            int err = av_buffersrc_write_frame(buffer_ctx, frame);
        //            if (err < 0) {
        //                LOGE("error writing frame to buffersrc");
        //                return -1;
        //            }
        //            // pull filtered video from the filtergraph
        //            for (;;) {
        //                int err = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, oframe);
        //                if (err == AVERROR_EOF || err == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
        //                    break;
        //                if (err < 0) {
        //                    LOGE("error reading buffer from buffersink");
        //                    return -1;
        //                }
        //            }
        //
        //            LOGI("output frame");

        err = av_interleaved_write_frame(outCtx, &packet);
        if (err < 0) {
            printf("error at write frame");
            return -1;
        }

        //}
    }

    av_free_packet(&packet);
}

av_write_trailer(outCtx);
if (!(outCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE) && outCtx->pb)
    avio_close(outCtx->pb);

avformat_free_context(outCtx);
avformat_close_input(&inCtx);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: _make a ffmpeg command line utility_ - you don't want to use `ffmpeg.c` file, or you don't want to run `ffmpeg` as a child process?

Comment: I currently am not using ffmpeg.c, what i'm doing in my program is opening my file than making AVFilters that I apply to each of the frames and then I write these frames out to a output stream and write back onto the phone

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for [`vf_crop`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/vf__crop_8c-source.html).

The [`CropContext`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/structCropContext.html) contains a `x`, `y`, `w`, and `h`, which should be what you need to crop a video to a specific width and height.

Comment: This looks like it may be what im looking for however im not exactly sure how to implement it.  So I open the file input and get a reference to AVFormatContext do I apply this AVFilterContext to this ?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with ffmpeg/libavfilter, you should be able to find what you need [their documentation](https://libav.org/documentation.html). It looks like they have automated tests, look through that for a vf_crop test for some code.